# reference multiple values returned from a function in kivy code

Tags: python, kivy

I generate textvalues in a function for a kivy label. I have this function (callback) and I am able to return and use 1 value.

However I can also store multiple values but I dont know how to access them inside the kivy block. So I can return just labeltext and use it in the kivy block with self.parent.callback(self). How can I access the values in the list?

here is my code:

```
def callback(self, btn_instance):

    labeltext = dict[num1]
    labeltextdef = dict[num2]

    return (labeltext, labeltextdef)
```

the kivy-code in the same file with builder.load_string.

```
Label:
    text: self.parent.callback(self) # here should be a way to reference labeltext, respectively labeltextdef
```

Comment: Have you tried just indexing the result as `text: self.parent.callback(self)[1]`?

Comment: I tried now and it worked :) lol